# How to set chart title above y-axis?

Tags: c#, charts, console-application, asp.net-charts

I have been experimenting with charts and so far I got this experimental code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();

        Chart thisChart = new Chart();

        thisChart.Height = 400;
        thisChart.Width = 500;
        thisChart.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;
        thisChart.Palette = ChartColorPalette.EarthTones;
        thisChart.Titles.Add("Test");
        thisChart.Visible = true;

        ChartArea ca = new ChartArea();
        ca.Name = "Default";
        ca.BackColor = Color.White;
        ca.BorderColor = Color.FromArgb(26, 59, 105);
        ca.BorderWidth = 0;
        ca.BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
        ca.AxisX = new Axis();
        ca.AxisY = new Axis();
        thisChart.ChartAreas.Add(ca);

        Series series = thisChart.Series.Add("Default");
        series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
        series.ChartArea = "Default";
        series.Points.AddXY("1", 20);
        series.Points.AddXY("2", 25);
        series.Points.AddXY("3", 30);
        series.Points.AddXY("4", 35);
        series.Points.AddXY("5", 40);
        series.Points.AddXY("6", 45);

        //SetPosition for multiple Y-axis labels
        thisChart.ChartAreas["Default"].Position = new ElementPosition(25, 10, 68, 85);
        thisChart.ChartAreas["Default"].InnerPlotPosition = new ElementPosition(10, 0, 90, 80);

        // Create extra Y axis for second and third series
        Series series2 = thisChart.Series.Add("Series2");
        series2.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
        series2.ChartArea = "Default";
        series2.Points.AddXY("1", 50);
        series2.Points.AddXY("2", 55);
        series2.Points.AddXY("3", 60);
        series2.Points.AddXY("4", 70);
        series2.Points.AddXY("5", 75);
        series2.Points.AddXY("6", 80);
        //series2.Legend = "Default";

        thisChart.Series["Series2"].ChartArea = "Default";
        CreateYAxis(thisChart, thisChart.ChartAreas["Default"], thisChart.Series["Series2"], 13, 8);

        // Create extra X axis for second and third series
        Series series3 = thisChart.Series.Add("Series3");
        series3.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
        series3.ChartArea = "Default";
        series3.Points.AddXY("1,5", 75);
        series3.Points.AddXY("2,5", 175);
        series3.Points.AddXY("3,5", 300);
        series3.Points.AddXY("4,5", 75);
        series3.Points.AddXY("5,5", 150);
        series3.Points.AddXY("6,6", 125);

        thisChart.Series["Series3"].ChartArea = "Default";
        CreateXAxis(thisChart, thisChart.ChartAreas["Default"], thisChart.Series["Series3"], -10, 8);

        //thisChart.DataBind();
        thisChart.SaveImage(@"C:\Temp\TestChart.png", ChartImageFormat.Png);

    }

    private static void CreateYAxis(Chart chart, ChartArea area, Series series, float axisOffset, float labelsSize)
    {
        // Create new chart area for original series
        ChartArea areaSeries = chart.ChartAreas.Add("ChartArea_" + series.Name);
        areaSeries.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        areaSeries.BorderColor = Color.Transparent;
        areaSeries.Position.FromRectangleF(area.Position.ToRectangleF());
        areaSeries.InnerPlotPosition.FromRectangleF(area.InnerPlotPosition.ToRectangleF());
        areaSeries.AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        areaSeries.AxisX.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
        areaSeries.AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
        areaSeries.AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        areaSeries.AxisY.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
        areaSeries.AxisY.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
        areaSeries.AxisY.IsStartedFromZero = area.AxisY.IsStartedFromZero;
        areaSeries.AxisY.TitleAlignment = StringAlignment.Far;
        areaSeries.AxisY.TextOrientation = TextOrientation.Horizontal;
        areaSeries.AxisY.Title = "Y-axis Title1";
        areaSeries.AxisY.TitleForeColor = Color.Blue;
        areaSeries.AxisY.TitleFont = new Font("Tahoma", 7, FontStyle.Bold);
        areaSeries.AxisY.Maximum = 300;


        series.ChartArea = areaSeries.Name;

        // Create new chart area for axis
        ChartArea areaAxis = chart.ChartAreas.Add("AxisY_" + series.ChartArea);
        areaAxis.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        areaAxis.BorderColor = Color.Transparent;
        areaAxis.Position.FromRectangleF(chart.ChartAreas[series.ChartArea].Position.ToRectangleF());
        areaAxis.InnerPlotPosition.FromRectangleF(chart.ChartAreas[series.ChartArea].InnerPlotPosition.ToRectangleF());
        areaAxis.AxisY.TitleAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        areaAxis.AxisY.Title = "Y-axis Title";
        areaAxis.AxisY.TitleForeColor = Color.Blue;
        areaAxis.AxisY.TitleFont = new Font("Tahoma", 7, FontStyle.Bold);
        areaAxis.AxisY.TitleAlignment = StringAlignment.Far;
        areaAxis.AxisY.TextOrientation = TextOrientation.Horizontal;
        areaAxis.AxisY.Maximum = 200;


        // Create a copy of specified series
        Series seriesCopy = chart.Series.Add(series.Name + "_Copy");
        seriesCopy.ChartType = series.ChartType;
        foreach (DataPoint point in series.Points)
        {
            seriesCopy.Points.AddXY(point.XValue, point.YValues[0]);
        }

        // Hide copied series
        seriesCopy.IsVisibleInLegend = false;
        seriesCopy.Color = Color.Transparent;
        seriesCopy.BorderColor = Color.Transparent;
        seriesCopy.ChartArea = areaAxis.Name;

        // Disable drid lines & tickmarks
        areaAxis.AxisX.LineWidth = 0;
        areaAxis.AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        areaAxis.AxisX.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
        areaAxis.AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
        areaAxis.AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        areaAxis.AxisY.IsStartedFromZero = area.AxisY.IsStartedFromZero;
        areaAxis.AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = area.AxisY.LabelStyle.Font;

        // Adjust area position
        areaAxis.Position.X -= axisOffset;
        areaAxis.InnerPlotPosition.X += labelsSize;

    }

    private static void CreateXAxis(Chart chart, ChartArea area, Series series, float axisOffset, float labelsSize)
    {
        // Create new chart area for original series
        ChartArea areaSeries = chart.ChartAreas.Add("ChartArea_" + series.Name);
        areaSeries.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        areaSeries.BorderColor = Color.Transparent;
        areaSeries.Position.FromRectangleF(area.Position.ToRectangleF());
        areaSeries.InnerPlotPosition.FromRectangleF(area.InnerPlotPosition.ToRectangleF());

        areaSeries.AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        areaSeries.AxisY.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
        areaSeries.AxisY.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;

        areaSeries.AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        areaSeries.AxisX.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
        areaSeries.AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
        areaSeries.AxisX.IsStartedFromZero = area.AxisX.IsStartedFromZero;

        series.ChartArea = areaSeries.Name;

        // Create new chart area for axis
        ChartArea areaAxis = chart.ChartAreas.Add("AxisX_" + series.ChartArea);
        areaAxis.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        areaAxis.BorderColor = Color.Transparent;
        areaAxis.Position.FromRectangleF(chart.ChartAreas[series.ChartArea].Position.ToRectangleF());
        areaAxis.InnerPlotPosition.FromRectangleF(chart.ChartAreas[series.ChartArea].InnerPlotPosition.ToRectangleF());



        // Create a copy of specified series
        Series seriesCopy = chart.Series.Add(series.Name + "_Copy");
        seriesCopy.ChartType = series.ChartType;
        foreach (DataPoint point in series.Points)
        {
            seriesCopy.Points.AddXY(point.XValue, point.YValues[0]);
        }

        // Hide copied series
        seriesCopy.IsVisibleInLegend = false;
        seriesCopy.Color = Color.Transparent;
        seriesCopy.BorderColor = Color.Transparent;
        seriesCopy.ChartArea = areaAxis.Name;

        // Disable drid lines & tickmarks
        areaAxis.AxisY.LineWidth = 0;
        areaAxis.AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        areaAxis.AxisY.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
        areaAxis.AxisY.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;

        areaAxis.AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        //areaAxis.AxisX.IntervalOffset = Convert.ToDouble("0,5");
        areaAxis.AxisX.IsStartedFromZero = area.AxisX.IsStartedFromZero;
        areaAxis.AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = area.AxisX.LabelStyle.Font;

        areaAxis.AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(0, 1, "0.5");
        areaAxis.AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(1, 2, "1.5");
        areaAxis.AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(2, 3, "2.5");
        areaAxis.AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(3, 4, "3.5");
        areaAxis.AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(4, 5, "4.5");
        areaAxis.AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(5, 6, "5.5");
        areaAxis.AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(6, 7, "6.5");

        // Adjust area position
        areaAxis.Position.Y -= axisOffset;
        areaAxis.InnerPlotPosition.Y += labelsSize;

    }
```

This produces the following result:

[image]

**PROBLEM:**

I can not figure out how to make it so that the title aligns itself above the respective y-axis, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you do that.

Afaik the recommended workaround is adding more chart `Titles`.

You can style them as usual and to move them on top of a axis you can align them to the top left of the respective `Chartearea.InnerPlotPosition`:

```
ChartArea ca1 = thisChart.ChartAreas[0];
RectangleF rip1 = ca1.InnerPlotPosition.ToRectangleF();
Title ty1 = thisChart.Titles.Add("ty1");
ty1.Text = "Y-Axis 1\nTitle";
ty1.ForeColor = Color.DarkSlateBlue;
ty1.Position.X = rip1.Left;
ty1.Position.Y = rip1.Y;
```

Make sure to have enough space at the top of the chart for the titles..

[image]

Do note that the values of all `ElementPositions`, including `InnerPlotPosition` are in **percent** of the respective **containers**, i.e. of the `ChartArea` for the `InnerPlotPosition` and of the `Chart` for the `ChartArea`..

Comment: Thanks m8! been at ths for a while, happy to finaly found an answer